# how to register new user (users & permission) via api in strapi v4?

Tags: javascript, strapi

I'm trying to register a new user via API in strapi v4.2.0, but I keep getting error 400 that says

> { "data": null,
> "error":{
> "status": 400,
> "name": "ApplicationError",
> "message": "An error occurred during account creation",
> "details":{}
> }
> }

here is the data that I send via **POST** to *http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local/register*

```
{ 
  "username":"testingg",
  "email":"test@gmail.com",
  "password": "password"
}
```

header: `Content-Type: application/json`

here is the strapi users & permission setting page
[strapi users & permission setting page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WNrl.png)

here is the error log from the console

````
[2022-06-25 13:35:33.360] error: 2 errors occurred ValidationError: 2 errors occurred
at handleYupError (D:\Documents\Projects\indihome\web\api\node_modules\@strapi\utils\lib\validators.js:63:9)
at D:\Documents\Projects\indihome\web\api\node_modules\@strapi\utils\lib\validators.js:73:5
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async Object.create (D:\Documents\Projects\indihome\web\api\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\lib\services\ent)ity-service\index.js:164:23)
at async Object.<anonymous> (D:\Documents\Projects\indihome\web\api\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\lib\services\entity-service\index.js:67:20)                                                                               ity-service\index.js:164:
at async Object.register (D:\Documents\Projects\indihome\web\api\node_modules\@strapi\plugin-users-permissions\server\controllers\auth.js:339:20)                                                                         s\entity-service\index.js
at async returnBodyMiddleware (D:\Documents\Projects\indihome\web\api\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\lib\services\server\compose-endpoint.js:52:18)                                                                          ons\server\controllers\au
at async policiesMiddleware (D:\Documents\Projects\indihome\web\api\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\lib\services\server\policy.js:24:5)                                                                                       ces\server\compose-endpoi
at async D:\Documents\Projects\indihome\web\api\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\lib\middlewares\body.js:51:9   
at async D:\Documents\Projects\indihome\web\api\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\lib\middlewares\logger.js:22:5 s\server\policy.js:24:5) 
at async D:\Documents\Projects\indihome\web\api\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\lib\middlewares\powered-by.js:16:5
at async cors (D:\Documents\Projects\indihome\web\api\node_modules\@koa\cors\index.js:56:32)               6:5
at async D:\Documents\Projects\indihome\web\api\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\lib\middlewares\errors.js:13:7 
at async session (D:\Documents\Projects\indihome\web\api\node_modules\koa-session\index.js:41:7)
at async D:\Documents\Projects\indihome\web\api\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\lib\services\metrics\middleware.js:29:5
    ```
````

Comment: I know that Strapi has some password requirements such as "at least 1 uppercase, a number etc". I don't know if "password" is an example purely used for this SO question? Because I believe that could be causing trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, turned out strapi allows / requires passing a role and a password, and you need to pass the role by ID. "1" is the Authenticated.

Here is a `curl` command that you can import into postman to work with, just adjust your bearer token and adjust the `post` data to the format your user data requires.

**Security Note**: I heavily advise to add your own logic to this API route to adjust which roles the users of a specific role may give to newly created users for safety reasons (privilege escalation is the topic here)

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:1337/api/users' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer yourToken' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "username": "foo",
  "email": "bar@gmail.com",
  "password": "somePassword",
  "role" : "1",
  "twoFA" : { "twoFAmethod" : "email" }
}'
```

**Another security note:** It makes no sense that you are allowed to set the user password, here I would adjust the route to ignore this, set some cryptic default password, and send an email with a password reset (with context-adjusted wording of course though).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.

What I did was add `console.log(yupError.errors);` line to the class `YupValidationError` in `errors.js`
*(node_modules@strapi\plugin-users-permissions\node_modules@strapi\utils\lib\errors.js)*

```
class YupValidationError extends ValidationError {
  constructor(yupError, message) {
    super();
    console.log(yupError.errors);
    const { errors, message: yupMessage } = formatYupErrors(yupError);
    this.message = message || yupMessage;
    this.details = { errors };
  }
}
```

So, the next time you gonna be able to see the real error.
*PD: Dont forget to restart strapi server after changing the file!*

**[Extra info that can be usefull]**
In my case, even when the payload had all the fields I'm getting this errors:

```
[
  'email is a required field',
  'username is a required field',
  'password is a required field'
]
```

so i added a `console.log()` to see the value of `ctx.request.body` and then I'd noticed that the payload was inside an object with the `data` key:

```
{
  data: {
    username: 'testing',
    email: 'testing2@gmail.com',
    password: '123456'
  }
}
```

I hope it works for you!